# Code::Blocks Windows GTK Build Error

Tags: c, gtk, codeblocks, gtk3, build-error

I use codeblocks and a GTK 3.x version. After the installation, I wanted to try it. The following build message came up

> cannot find -lgtk-win32-2.0

Can someone help me. Thank you

Comment: If you're using `GTK 3.x version`, then you might need to provide library option for 3.0 version. `-lgtk-win32-2.0` looks like it would try to use GTK 2.0

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, by default, codeblocks is configured to use Gtk+-2.0:

```
gcc -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng15 -Wall -g  -c /root/test/main.c -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/test obj/Debug/main.o  -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype
```

So, you need to tell it to switch to `Gtk+-3.0`. It's not entirely easy to get there. In Project, select Properties:

[image]

There, go to Project's Build Options, at the bottom:

[image]

Then, switch to Linker Settings:

[image]

To the right is the pkg-config call to obtain the options you can see in the `gcc` calls at the top of this answer. Changing `2.0` into `3.0` will call the options for `Gtk+-3.0`.

Note: Be careful when editing to preserve the 'back-ticks' (the inverse 'accents' or single quotes).

Also note the Gtk library is *really* called `gtk+`, so version `3.0` is called `gtk+-3.0` (eg. for use with `pkg-config`).

That should do it.

Comment: I have on Link Libraries:  gtk-win32-2.0 ||  gobject-2.0  || glib-2.0. On Other linker options i write : `pkg-config gtk+2.0 --libs`
but it doesnt working

Comment: Please pay attention, jcoppens told you to type `gtk+-3.0`, not `gtk-2.0`. That's `gtk`, then a plus (`+`), then a dash (`-`), then `3.0`.

Comment: Thanks @liberforce. The whole +- issue is rather confusing. I edited the text a little.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. The fact is that the toolkit was named `gtk`and became `gtk+` a long time ago, when it has been transformed to be more object-oriented. The dash is there as a separator between the package name and the package version, versions 1.x, 2.x and 3.x (and in the near future, 4.x) of GTK to be installable in parallel.